# How to pass a computed property as a style property value for a component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

The template of my component contains this html element:

```
.grid-item(:style="{ width: columnWidth, backgroundColor: 'blue' }")
```

and I'd like to set its width value using a computed property:

```
computed: {
  columnWidth () {
    return ((this.maxWidth - ( this.marginWidth * 2)) - ((this.columnsCount - 1) * this.gutterWidth)) / this.columnsCount;
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this in a correct manner?

The problem is obviously in the `:style="{ width: columnWidth` part
since every thing works perfectly when I set this `width:'20px'` for example.

Comment: You probably need to append some units.

Comment: that's very likely! I'm looking up the correct syntax of doing this right now.

Comment: Thank you! It was in the official Vue documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I had to append a unit to the columnWidth value in the inline style.

`width: columnWidth + 'px'` did the trick.